# Media Queries use only biggest width

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-website

i have problem with media queries that it always replace the biggest query idk why ! 
here is my code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
     .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 35px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 55px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 65px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

i also have the viewport meta at my html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but at the browser it shows up like this : 
 "Note: browser width : 980"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgWFN.png)

thanks

Comment: use `!important` like: `color: #36260d !important;` to prevent it from getting overridden

Comment: maybe you did not activate the "responsive mode" when debugging?

Comment: Did u try like this `@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 575px)`

Comment: @Ajeesh KH do the trick thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put your media query order like this large to small

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 65px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {

    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 55px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 35px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
     .sectionHeader{
        color: #36260d;
        font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 20px;
        line-height: 55px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the desired results for each resolution then you have use the min-width and max-width property. So that it will apply specific styles on the given range of min and max width.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
 .sectionHeader{
    color: #36260d;
    font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    line-height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:576px) and (max-width: 768px) {
.sectionHeader{
    color: #36260d;
    font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    line-height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
 }
@media screen and (min-width:769px)  and (max-width: 992px) {

.sectionHeader{
    color: #36260d;
    font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 55px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    line-height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width:993px)  and (max-width: 1200px) {
.sectionHeader{
    color: #36260d;
    font-family: BebasNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 65px;
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    line-height: 55px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s8kghf6o/)